# Problems with imshow update

Tags: image, matlab

Why is the image in a figure (ploted by `imshow`) changing its size when updated by another `imshow`?

Demonstrational Code:

```
img = rand(100,100);
figure(1);
hold on;
imshow(img); % plot an image
pause(1);    % pause for demonstrational reasons
imshow(img); % update the image
```

This is only happening at the first update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

figure(1); takes default size and then when you plot imshow(img) after hold on size gets reduced relative previous figure(1) size.

Better approach would be

```
img = rand(100,100);
figure, imshow(img); % plot an image
hold on;
pause(1);    % pause for demonstrational reasons
imshow(img); % update the image
```

Answer (score -2):

The image is not changing size. You can see this by typing:

```
img = rand(100,100);
figure(1);
hold on;
whos img
pause(5);   
whos img
```

the following will be your result:

```
Name        Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  img       100x100            80000  double              

  Name        Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  img       100x100            80000  double
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is a nonsense answer ;-)